# how to check if a client´s request is a http request? node js

Tags: node.js

i have a TCP server which receives requests from clients. i want to make sure it is a http request.

this is my server:

```
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.setEncoding("utf8");
    console.log("Connections stated by:" + socket.address().address);
    socket.write("hi tcp\r\n");
    socket.on("data",function(chunk) {
        console.log("received the following data: " + chunk);
        var request = requestParser.parseRequest(chunk);
    });         
});
```

in requestParser i parse chunk and take the method and request with `querystring` but how do i know that it is an http request? i have to parse the 3rd parameter of the request to check it it's equals to `HTTP/1.1`? is there a function that can do that for me?

thank u !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the [http module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.6/api/all.html#hTTP)?